# SQL Server 2019 : select just inserted row

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with id set as primary_key/is_identity, so I was wondering if I can assume the correctness in finding the row just inserted using `SELECT TOP 1` in the middle of `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT TRANSACTION` by using a reverse order:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

INSERT INTO [MyTable] ([description], [name])
VALUES ('animal', 'cat')

SELECT TOP (1) [id], [description], [name]
FROM [MyTable]
ORDER BY [id] DESC

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Is that always correct, considering the mentioned constraints and the transaction instructions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot rely on `TOP (1)` to get the row you inserted, because someone else could have inserted a row *after* you did but *before* your select, yes even inside a transaction. In high concurrency this is going to lead to tears, unless you make your transaction serializable. But that is unnecessary, since you can *always* get the row(s) *you* inserted using the `inserted` pseudo-table:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable ([description], [name])
OUTPUT inserted.id, inserted.description, inserted.name
VALUES ('animal', 'cat');
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a4df3fe4c214369e937024b0c8fb8077)

For single-row inserts, yes, you can use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`, but `OUTPUT` works for both single-row and multi-row inserts.

Comment: Thanks,, you and @marc_s give me both a good answer, also with solutions. Yours is a bit more elaborated so I'm going to accept this one.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is **NOT** safe - if multiple inserts happen at the same time, just selecting the `TOP 1` could give you a wrong result!

You need to rely on the `ID` that was just inserted:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

INSERT INTO [MyTable] ([description], [name])
VALUES ('animal', 'cat')

-- this fetches the IDENTITY "ID" of your row having been inserted
DECLARE @NewID INT = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

-- get that freshly inserted row of your context/scope
SELECT [id], [description], [name]
FROM [MyTable]
WHERE id = @NewID;

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: Thanks so much. You and Aaron give me good answers and both with solutions. But I have to accept one, I decide for Aaron's one because of its detailed explanation. Thaks again anyway.

Comment: @Mike97: it's hard to give a better response when Aaron jumps in ;-)